# Query/Find to Return JSON Object in a BsonDocument

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-query, bson

I have a document like this:

```
    { "File" : "xxxxxxx.txt",
      "Content" : [
          {   "tag" : "Book",
              "name" : "TestBook1",
              "value" : "xxx"
          },
          {   "tag" : "Dept",
              "name" : "TestDept1",
              "value" : "yyy"
          },
          {   "tag" : "Employee", 
              "name" : "TestEmployee1",
              "value" : "zzz"
          }]
    }
```

I can find the document by using:

```
var filter = Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter.Eq("Content.tag", "Dept");
var result = collection.Find(filter).ToList();
```

However, this returns the whole document. Is there any way to just get the JSON object (`{"tag" : "Dept", "name" : "TestDept1"}`)?

What I'm trying to get is just the "value" property (in this case, it's "yyy"), instead of the whole document.

**UPDATE:**

Like Phani suggested, I was able to make this work with the following code:

```
var subFilter = Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter.Eq("tag", "Dept");
var filter = Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter.ElemMatch("Content", subFilter);
var result =
    collection.Find(filter)
        .Project(Builders<BsonDocument>.Projection.Exclude("_id").Include("Content.$"))
        .ToList();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the ElemMatch projection for this.

Shell query for this : db.testing.find({Content:{$elemMatch:{"tag":"Dept"}}},{"_id":0,"Content.$":1})

C# query will be

`Find(x => x.Content.Any(p => p.tag == "Dept")).Project(Builders<BsonDocument>.Projection.Exclude("_id").Include("Content.$")).ToList();`

Please check if this is working.

Comment: Phani, thanks for the reply. Unfortunately, I can't have a POCO class for my JSON because the object structure in Content is dynamic. I use a fix structure just for the simplicity sake. Is there any way not to use a POCO class in LINQ to make this work?

Comment: Phani, I was able to use .Project as you suggested in combination of Filter to only include the Content object. However this returns the entire Content object. Is there a way to further filter the result so it only contains the Dept part in the Content?

Comment: Phani, thanks again for your reply. I think I got it. I'll update my post and accept your answer.

Comment: Phani, how would I do the Find if I also need to filter on the File field? I need to do the query like this: if File = "xxxxxxx.txt" and Content.tag = "Dept"

Comment: Yes you can do it like that.
Shell code would be like this  
`
db.testing.find({File:"xxxxxxx.txt",Content:{$elemMatch:{"tag":"Dept"}}},{"_id":0,"Content.$":1})

Comment: You can chain the Eq filter one after the other. Please let me know if you have any difficulty.
`
var filter = builder.Eq("File","xxxxxx.txt") & builder.ElemMatch("Content", subFilter);
`
Something like that you can do.